# How can i use a duration setting on .animate if it is inside the callback from a .fadeOut effect?

Tags: jquery, callback, jquery-animate, fadeout, duration

I am trying to just fade the content of `section#secondary` out and once the content has been faded out, the parent (`section#secondary`) should animate 'shut' in a slider animation.

All this is working however the durations are not and I cannot figure out why.

Here is my code:

**HTML**

```
<section id="secondary">
    <a href="#" class="slide_button">&laquo;</a> <!-- slide in/back button -->              
    <article>

        <h1>photos</h1>
        <div class="album_nav"><a href="#">photo 1 of 6</a> | <a href="#">create an album</a></div>
        <div class="bar">
            <p class="section_title">current image title</p>
        </div>

        <section class="image">

            <div class="links"> 
                <a class="_back album_link" href="#">« from the album: james new toy</a>
                <nav>
                    <a href="#" class="_back small_button">back</a>
                    <a href="#" class="_next small_button">next</a>
                </nav>
            </div>  

            <img src="http://localhost/~jannis/3781_doggie_wonderland/www/preview/static/images/sample-image-enlarged.jpg" width="418" height="280" alt="" />

        </section>

    </article>

    <footer>
        <embed src="http://localhost/~jannis/3781_doggie_wonderland/www/preview/static/flash/secondary-footer.swf" wmode="transparent" width="495" height="115" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" />
    </footer>

</section> <!-- close secondary -->
```

**jQuery**

```
// =============================
// = Close button (slide away) =
// =============================
$('a.slide_button').click(function() {
    $(this).closest('section#secondary').children('*').fadeOut('slow', function() {
        $('section#secondary').animate({'width':'0'}, 3000);
    });
});
```

Because the content of `section#secondary` is variable I use the `*` selector.

What happens is that the `fadeOut` uses the appropriate `slow` speed but as soon as the callback fires *(once the content is faded out)* the `section#secondary` animates to `width: 0` within a couple of milliseconds and not the 3000 ms ( 3 sec ) I set the animation duration to.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

PS: I cannot post an example at this point but since this is more a matter of theory of jQuery I don't think an example is necessary here. *Correct me if I am wrong..*

Comment: This is not the behavior I'm seeing with only this code: http://jsfiddle.net/eKeQ2/ Something external/additional must be going on in your actual page.  A check of `$('section#secondary:not(:animated)')` should be done though, since you're starting that animation for each faded child instead of just once.

Comment: I updated my answer. I'm guessing it is because you don't have any size properties set for `#secondary`, so when its content is removed, it automatically collapses to nothing. My new answer (below) sets its size statically when you click, and just before the animation.

Answer (score 0):

I believe at least one potential problem here is that the callback from `.fadeOut()` (which then calls the `.animate()`) may execute multiple times for the number of children elected from `.children('*')`.  This should probably be reworked in such a way that the callback is only executed once.

Answer (score 0):

are you sure the width has changed to 0? running the following sample I can see the width is not 0 until the first callback is fired.

note that the callback is fired once per first level child, therefore 3 times in this sample

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">

            $(document).ready(function() {
                $('a.slide_button').click(function() {
                    $('div#secondary').children().fadeOut('slow',function(){
                        // this has scope of the html element
                        console.log(this);
                        console.log($(this).parent().width());
                        $(this).parent().animate({'width':'0'}, 3000, function(){
                            console.log($(this).width());
                        });
                    });
                });
            });

        </script>
    </head>
    <body>

        <div id="secondary" style="background: red;">          
            <a href="#" class="slide_button">&laquo;</a> <!-- slide in/back button -->  
            <div>

                <h1>photos</h1>
                <div class="album_nav"><a href="#">photo 1 of 6</a> | <a href="#">create an album</a></div>
                <div class="bar">
                    <p class="section_title">current image title</p>
                </div>

                <div class="image">

                    <div class="links"> 
                        <a class="_back album_link" href="#">« from the album: james new toy</a>
                        <nav>
                            <a href="#" class="_back small_button">back</a>
                            <a href="#" class="_next small_button">next</a>
                        </nav>
                    </div>  

                </div>

            </div>

            <div>
                <p>Footer</p>
            </div>

       </div>

    </body>
</html>
```